# I need to convert binary into hexadecimal : below is the code:

Tags: python-2.7, binary, hex, type-conversion

bv2 stores the value  as 00110001001100100000101000000000

//bv2 is initialized as
bv2 =  BitVector( intVal = 0, size = 32 )

//then some bit operation is done
bv2=bv1^bv2

hex(int(bv2,2))

this is giving me error.However if I directly use hex(int('00110001001100100000101000000000',2)) it gives me hexadecimal result.
What is wrong here?

Comment: what is the error message you get?

Comment: Please include the full traceback, and show us how the variable `bv2` is assigned the binary value.

Comment: bv2 = BitVector( intVal = 0, size = 32 )

Answer (score 0):

The `base` argument is used only for strings or bytes. `BitVector` has a proper `__int__()` method.

```
hex(int(bv2))
```